# Cannot check title's value in twig, Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have the following in a custom text field in a view:

```
<h5 class="rates_title">{{title}}</h5>
{%if field_car%}
<p class="car">{{field_car}}
  {%if title != "Home" %}
  <span class="small_caps">car</span>
  {%endif%}
</p>
{%else%}
<p class="view-details"><a href="/">View Details</a></p>
{%endif%}
```

Everything works except the `{%if title != "Home" %}` part. Every item gets the span tag, even Home, which I do not want. Yes, the title is Home, and I can confirm that in the `<h5>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` at that point is an array and needs to be rendered but then it will contain html tags so you need to search `in` that rendered string for `Home` like this

```
{% if 'Home' in title|render %}
    <span class="small_caps">car</span>
{% endif %}
```